# Android adb connect: permission denied

Tags: android, adb, wear-os

I'm developing an app with some friends for wearables.
I wanted to get the app on my device (Moto360) through adb.
I read many Guides and forums but none had the same failure.

I have enabled blueooth debugging on both my tablet (Samsung Series S) and my Moto360. I have connected my watch to the tablet and the tablet with my PC(Samsung Series 7, Windows 8.1).

When i run the commands:

```
adb forward tcp:4444 localhost:/adb-hub
adb connect:4444
```

I get this:
[Connection denied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6g6l4.png)

I already tried to delete all permissions, reboot my tablet and watch and other hints I got on various pages.

On my friends PC I under Ubuntu i had no problem with connecting the pc and my devices.

Comment: Why don't you connect your PC directly with your smartwatch and run it directly through android studio? After that you will have the app installed on your device

Comment: How do I connect it directly?

Comment: Through a usb/micro-usb cable, just like your phone!

Comment: Okay now i understand. Like I wrote I use a Moto360 which doesn't have a port for mirco-usb cable or any other cable